# Using requests with gunicorn gevent worker creating high latency

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, gunicorn, gevent

I am using gevent workers with gunicorn for my flask application that exposes some http endpoint. Within this http endpoint execution flow I make a request to another http endpoint to fetch some data. I use the same endpoint for all requests so I am also reusing the same requests.session.My `rest_client.py` to fetch data using requests looks something like this :

```
import requests
import json
import os
import time

class RestClient:
    base_url = None
    session = None

    def __init__(self):            
        if not RestClient.session:
            RestClient.base_url = f"http://localhost:5000"
            RestClient.session = requests.session()

    def fetch_http(self, key: str, name: str) -> str:
        fetch_http_endpoint = f"{self.base_url}/client/get-result"
        query_params = {"key": key, "name": name}

       
        session_get_start_time = time.time() * 1000
        response = self.session.get(fetch_http_endpoint, params=query_params)
        session_get_end_time = time.time() * 1000
        session_get_total_time = session_get_end_time - session_get_start_time
        print(f"session.get total time {session_get_total_time}")
        if response.status_code == 200:
            parsed_json = json.loads(response.content)
            result = parsed_json["result"]
            return result
```

My `gunicorn.py` config is pretty simple:

```
PORT = os.getenv("PORT", 5000)
RELOAD = os.getenv("DEBUG", False)

bind = f"0.0.0.0:{PORT}"
workers = 1  # Only run one worker at a time, we deploy in k8s
worker_class = "gevent"  # Async workers
reload = RELOAD
```

I only use 1 worker for this demo but I think that shouldn't matter for this demonstration.

the code debug prints when using gevent workers:

```
session.get total time 28710.727783203125
session.get total time 23681.550048828125
session.get total time 18187.310302734375
session.get total time 21550.77294921875
session.get total time 20483.166259765625
session.get total time 10297.47705078125
session.get total time 5146.256103515625
```

the response time are much faster when using sync workers (again single worker only) which seems counter intuitive because gevent is meant to be more performant for IO bound applications.
the code debug prints when using sync workers:

```
session.get total time 41.621826171875
session.get total time 35.197998046875
session.get total time 24.538818359375
session.get total time 25.270751953125
session.get total time 21.31787109375
session.get total time 27.0400390625
```

My application has been using gevent worker for very long time now. But now when I want to introduce this change where I need to call another http endpoint only then I am seeing this issue, so I really want to use gevent workers

I have tried explicitly monkey patching before importing requests as suggested in some other answers related to this scenario but that didn't work.

Additionally I was able to configure datadog profiler which tells a code hotspot at

```
sleep (hub.py) at line 166 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/hub.py
```

Which I guess suggests that the event loop is getting blocked. But I don't know why this would be happening.

So here is what I am looking for help on

1. What could be the issue when using gevent workers.?
2. Could it be the case that requests is not getting monkey patched ? is there a way I can know about it ?
3. Why would sync worker perform better for this simple demo ?

versions being used in my application

```
python==3.8
requests==2.24.0
gevent==21.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

Comment: this only happens when there are concurrent requests running on  even with a very small load

Comment: I wrote a separate simple standalone application having only gunicorn with gevent workers and requests  and was unable to reproduce this issue. So some issue with my complete application only, but cannot figure out what.

Comment: It may be an environmental issue - i.e. are you sure you are not running out of RAM or CPU when running them concurrently?

Comment: neither CPU nor RAM usage is getting close to what's allocated to the pods

Comment: Maybe the service you are talking to doesn't handle concurrent requests well?